# Evaluating $\sum\limits_{i=1}^8 \cos\frac{\pi t_i}{4}$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^8 \cos^2\frac{\pi t_i}{4}$ for $t\in\{-7,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,7\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I am dealing with a series$$\sum_{i=1}^8 \cos\frac{\pi t_i}{4}$$
with $t\in\{-7,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,7\}$. How can I determine a global solution for this summation? Would it be the same logic for$$\sum_{i=1}^8 \cos^2\frac{\pi t_i}{4}?$$Many thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you name "a global solution"?

Comment: The sum of you question is 0.  The other sum evaluates to 4.

Answer (score 2):

You have a formula for the sum of sines or cosines of arcs in an arithmetic progression:

$$ \cos a + \cos(a + \theta )+\cos(a + 2 \theta )+ \dots + \cos(a + n \theta ) = \frac{\sin \frac{(n +1) \theta }{2}}{\sin \frac{ \theta }{2}}\,\cos\Bigl (a + \frac{n \theta }{2}\Bigr)$$
$$\sin a+ \sin(a + \theta )+ \sin(a + 2 \theta )+ \dots + \sin(a + n \theta ) = \frac{\sin \frac{(n + 1)\theta }{2}}{\sin \frac{\theta }{2}}\,\sin\Bigl (a + \frac{n \theta }{2}\Bigr),$$
that you can prove calculating the sum of the geometric progression
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\mathrm e^{i(a+k\theta)}=\mathrm e^{ia}\sum_{k=0}^n\mathrm e^{ik\theta}$$
and identifying the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: And as another hint, $\cos^2x=\dfrac{1+\cos2x}{2}$, so it can be done with the same method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need $$S_1=\sum_{r=-4}^3\cos\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}8\text{ ans }S_2=\sum_{r=-4}^3\cos^2\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}8$$

Clearly, $\cos8t=-1$ for $t=\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}8$ where $-8\le2n+1\le8\iff-4\le n\le3$

Using [this](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/trigonometry/multipleAngles.htm),

$$\cos8t=2^7\cos^8x-8\cdot2^5\cos^6x+\cdots+1$$

So, the roots of $$128c^8-256c^6+\cdots+2=0$$ are $\cos\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}8,-8\le2r+1\le8$

By Vieta's formula,
$$S_1=\dfrac0{128}$$ and $$S_2=S_1^2-2\left(-\frac{256}{128}\right)=?$$